# underscore template is not is not showing for popover function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js-templating

```
// html.erb(template)
<script id="temp">
 <p><%= name %></p><!--the name is to fetch value passed in template -->
</script>
```

---

```
//script.js
//declaring variables for template
var _slicer=$('#temp').html();
//popover function
$(linkingmoduleobj).popover({
        container : 'body',
        html : 'true',
        content : "some content,
        title : "some title",
        template : '_.template(_slicer,{name: "praveen"})'
    })
```

inside _.template when directly use the html code instead of passing variable it is working when i pass reference variable  for template it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script id="temp" type = "text/template">
     <p><%= name %></p>
</script>
<div id="aa"></div>
<script>
var _slicer=$('#temp').html();
//popover function
$('#aa').html(_.template(_slicer)({name: "praveen"}));
</script>
```

just change it the way you want to but the code to be changed is

```
_.template(_slicer)({name: "praveen"})
```

and

```
 <script id="temp" type = "text/template">
```

Comment: Thank you its worked fine. FYI i assingned the value for name seperately then i used _.template(_slicer,name) this is also worked.